# Raspberry Pi 3 - USB to Serial Communication in C# on Windows 10 IOT Core

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, win-universal-app, windows-10-iot-core, serial-communication

I am trying to Connect a Weighing Balance Device which has RS232 Serial Communication Port. It Gets Detected in Windows 10 PC & I can connect to it by using USB to Serial Converter through my Laptop's USB Port & I Can send & Receive Data using **.Net** applications.

But the Same Doesn't get Detected when I connect the Device to a USB Port on **Raspberry Pi 3**. I am using the Sample **UWP** application available on Git Hub

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/blob/345ac29fc98b388ab1c15f2a655dcc63e13e1259/Samples/SerialUART/CS/README.md#serial-uart

I am using **Windows 10 IOT Core 16299 Build** on Raspberry Pi 3

Some of the Forums suggest to get the Serial to USB Driver on Pi 3, Is there any one who has the drivers? I am not able to find any Serial to USB Converter which supports Windows 10 IOT Core.

Comment: I want to add FOUR Sensors using Windows 10 IOT. Is only one possible, or should I consider this solution from FTDI?                                          
  FT4232H - Hi-Speed Quad USB UART IC

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/hardwarecompatlist

At least 1 USB to Serial adapter is listed there.  There are others that probably work, and are not listed.

If you have the ARM32 driver for the adapter you are using, then you can load that into the OS using pnputil.exe or devcon.exe.

Comment: You can also just use the serial pins on the Raspberry Pi header itself.  No USB -> Serial adapter needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am new to Hardware Interaction Programs, Serial Adapter which I used doesn't have ARM 32 Driver, it's Just an RS232 Serial to USB Cable. Our Requirement is to Collect Data from Multiple Serial Ports and Receive & Store Data collected from each port into some Folder based on the Port ID. Is there any additional Hardware available which can directly connect multiple Serial Ports & We can write a program to Listen to each Port & dump the data in Raspberry Pi 3?

Comment: I don't know a lot about USB to Serial adapters, and I don't know which ones will work without a driver, OTHER than the one listed in the compatibility list.  Yes, you can write software to accept input from them and save that to files on disk.